# Getting all functions with prefix in C

Tags: c, posix, function-pointers

Is it possible to get function pointers to functions that have a prefix? At first I thought the names of c functions were lost during compilation. But then, dlsym returns the pointer to a function of a specified name.

So if there a way to do something like:

```
void * handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
*(void **)(&fptr);
while(fptr = dlsym(handle, "prefix*")) {
   fptr(args);
}
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic: There's no way to do something like this 'In c'.  You've correctly noticed that there *may* be a way to do it on <insert platform here>.  You may get a better answer if you get specific about that platform.

Comment: I've tagged as posix since `dlsym` and `dlopen` are posix.

Comment: The Linux dynamic loader provides those functions and the man page discusses `dlsym()` searching the symbol table tree.  Examining the source code of the library which implements those is likely to reveal a way to enumerate all symbols in the tree.

Comment: If this is entirely your program (and therefore you can change any part of it) you should just make an array of these function pointers in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @ooga, in that case I could just call each method manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by calling them manually. If you know their names, you could just call them in the usual way. Why do you want to do it the way you're trying to?

Comment: So that if in the future another method with the prefix is added then the array/function calls don't need to be updated

Comment: @Jonathan.:  If a new function *xyz* appears, how will the code know how to call it?  Certainly there is variability of return type, number of parameters, and parameter types.

Comment: @wallyk, no they all have the same arguments and return types. Like I want to call all functions that match the signature int process*(char *arg[])

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcA(int n) { printf("funcA: %d\n", n); }
void funcB(int n) { printf("funcB: %d\n", n); }
void funcC(int n) { printf("funcC: %d\n", n); }

void (*funcs[3]) (int n) = {
    funcA,
    funcB,
    funcC
};

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof funcs / sizeof *funcs; ++i)
        funcs[i](i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well this isn't a built-in way, and I don't think there is a built-in way... you could parse `nm`, but that is yucky.

but if you are building a plug in arch you can use an already known symbol to get all of the symbols.

lib.c

```
char ** functions()
{
    static char * f[3] = {"function1","function2",NULL};
    return f;
}

void function1()
{
    printf("function1\n");
}

void function2()
{
    printf("function2\n");
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef char ** (*functions)(void);
typedef void (*voidFunc)(void);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void * ref = dlopen("/abs/path/to/libExample.dylib",  RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    if (!ref)
    {
        printf("filed to open dylib: %i",errno);
    }

    functions f = dlsym(ref, "functions");

    if (f)
    {
        char** fnames = f();
        char * fname = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; 1 ; i++)
        {
            fname = fnames[i];
            if (fname) {
                voidFunc g = dlsym(ref, fname);
                if (g)
                {
                    g();
                }
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    dlclose(ref);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

outputs:

```
function1
function2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

not a linux way, but on OS X there is a some extra stuff that would probably be easier:

```
/*
 * Structure filled in by dladdr().
 */
typedef struct dl_info {
        const char      *dli_fname;     /* Pathname of shared object */
        void            *dli_fbase;     /* Base address of shared object */
        const char      *dli_sname;     /* Name of nearest symbol */
        void            *dli_saddr;     /* Address of nearest symbol */
} Dl_info;

extern int dladdr(const void *, Dl_info *);
```

Comment: A variable named `functions` is quite confusing (at least for me).

Comment: yeah more confusing that it is a typedef too :)